# How to use FreezedUnionCase.snake for model class

Tags: flutter, freezed, json-serializable

I am using freezed package as a code generator. My response from API as shown below,

```
first_name, 
last_name, 
etc..,
```

And I am defining my model class like this,

```
firstName,
lastName,
etc..,
```

If I use `@JsonKey(name: 'first_name')` then it works but I have to write this annotation for every field I have. Is there any way to set it global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this **@JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)** for snake_case convention

For Example

```
@freezed
class City with _$City {
  @JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
  const factory City({
    required int id,
    required String name,
    required int stateId,
    required String stateName,
  }) = _City;

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CityFromJson(json);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about `FieldRename.snake`?

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'event.freezed.dart';
part 'event.g.dart';

@freezed
class Event with _$Event {
  const Event._();

  @DocumentReferenceJsonConverter()
  @JsonSerializable(
    fieldRename: FieldRename.snake, // <---
  )
  factory Event({
    DocumentReference? reference, // reference
    String? eventTitle, // event_title
    String? eventDescription, // event_description
    String? eventLocation, // event_location
  }) = _Event;
}
```

json_annotation library [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/FieldRename.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Json to Dart Model](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hirantha.json-to-dart) can automate JSON conversion to `Freezed` data class.